# QuerySelectorAll working for some classes but not others

Tags: javascript, html, squarespace

I am trying to select some elements using a footer script on a Squareapace site. In the code below, I am able to get the '.event-time-12hr' class but not the '.item.item--ongoing' class. I have tried getting some parents of the second class but I can't get those either. Ajax is disabled for the site.

If I run the querySelector in the console of the browser after the page loads it works, so I assume it is a loading issue, I am not sure how to delay the script any longer.

```
<script >
(function() {
  if (window.NodeList && !NodeList.prototype.forEach) {
    NodeList.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;
  }

  document.addEventListener('readystatechange', event => {
    if (event.target.readyState === "complete") {
      init()
    }
  });

  function init() {
    var monthlyEl = document.querySelectorAll('.item.item--ongoing');
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.event-time-12hr');
    console.log('item--ongoing', monthlyEl.length)
    console.log('event time', elements.length)
  }

  new MutationObserver(function() {
    init();
    // myFunction2(); , etc...
  }).observe(document.body, {
    attributes: true,
    attributeFilter: ["class"]
  });
})();
</script>
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you support IE? Also, `(function() {` is always better written as `;(function() {`

Comment: You need to add sample HTML.

Comment: Which part of the code supports IE?

Comment: @user3511512 This one: `if (window.NodeList && !NodeList.prototype.forEach) {` If you don't need to support the dead IE, simply get rid of that one and join the club ;)

Comment: Also, when I run the querySelectorAll on this class in the browser it picks up the elements, so it is a loading issue. Not sure how get it after loading further than what I have done.

Comment: ok thanks. I pasted the code from a Squarespace forum so I didn't know that.

Comment: My guess is that the elements you're looking for are added dynamically. The `readystatechange` event occurs when the static HTML is loaded, but doesn't wait for dynamic elements that are added by JS (e.g. with AJAX). But the MutationObserver should handle that.

Comment: I checked and AJAX was already disabled for the site so it doesn't seem to be an AJAX issue.